# Speed up function for creating a list of triangles from mesh in R

Tags: r, performance, function

I wrote a function mesh2listri() in R that takes a kxm matrix and a tringulation structure matrix and returns a list where each element is a 3xm matrix defining the triangle. I really would like to speed up this function. However, I cannot figure out how to avoid the for loop. Thanks in advance for any help. Here below a fully reproducible example.

```
mesh2listri <- function(mat, tri) {
  if (ncol(tri) > 3) {
    tri <- t(tri)
  }
  res <- NULL
  for (i in 1:nrow(tri)) {
    resi <- mat[tri[i, ], ]
    res <- c(res, list(resi))
    print(i)
  }
  res
}

mat <- matrix(rnorm(90000, 0, 1), ncol = 3)
tri <- matrix(sample(1:30000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3)
system.time(mesh2listri(mat, tri))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something a little bit faster.

```
mesh2listri_byMinem <- function(mat, tri) {
  if (ncol(tri) > 3) tri <- t(tri)
  n <- nrow(tri)
  l <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    resi <- mat[tri[i, ], ]
    l[[i]] <- resi
  }
  l
}

# create larger data:
mat <- matrix(rnorm(6e6, 0, 1), ncol = 3)
tri <- matrix(sample(3e5, replace = T), ncol = 3)

b <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rez1 <- mesh2listri_new(mat, tri),
  rez2 <- mesh2listri_byMinem(mat, tri), times = 10, unit = "s"
)
options(digits = 2)
b
# Unit: seconds
#                                  expr   min   lq mean median   uq  max neval cld
#     rez1 <- mesh2listri_new(mat, tri) 0.630 0.85 0.94   0.85 0.92 1.86    10   b
# rez2 <- mesh2listri_byMinem(mat, tri) 0.092 0.10 0.11   0.10 0.10 0.15    10  a
```

Comment: "A little bit" is an understatement... nice job!

Comment: What a speed!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
mesh2listri <- function(mat, tri) {
  if (ncol(tri) > 3) tri <- t(tri)
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(tri)), function(i) mat[tri[i, ], ])
}
```

The problem in your code is that you are growing a new vector at each step.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be faster:

```
mesh2listri_lap<-function(mat,tri){
if(ncol(tri)>3){tri<-t(tri)}
res <- apply(tri, 1, function(x) mat[x,])
lapply(as.data.frame(res), function(x) matrix(x, nrow = 3, ncol = ncol(tri)))
}
```

New microbenchmark for the three answers:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(6e6, 0, 1), ncol = 3)
tri <- matrix(sample(3e5, replace = T), ncol = 3)

b <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rez1 <- mesh2listri_lap(mat, tri),
  rez2 <- mesh2listri_minem(mat, tri), 
  rez3 <- mesh2listri_prive(mat, tri),times = 10, unit = "s"
)
options(digits = 2)
b

> b
Unit: seconds
                                expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval cld
   rez1 <- mesh2listri_lap(mat, tri) 0.93 1.06 1.28   1.24 1.42 1.77    10   b
 rez2 <- mesh2listri_minem(mat, tri) 0.15 0.20 0.40   0.22 0.76 0.83    10  a 
 rez3 <- mesh2listri_prive(mat, tri) 0.22 0.29 0.31   0.30 0.35 0.45    10  a
```

Good job @minem and @F. Privé!

Comment: Wow! This is MUCH FASTER! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :) As I said, see if it works with other dimensions, you might need to change the `ncol` parameter in the `lapply()` call. Embarassingly, I'm no good with matrix algebra...